# Php DOM parse page behind a login form with redirect

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to parse a page after a login. I know how to login with curl, but on this site the login form is not conventional, the login page redirect to the form with a huge url containing key etc. website : https://pro.fluidra.com/fr_fr/customer/account/login/ then click on "connexion button, you'll have the login form. I have the login/password for my account on this site, but I don't know how to process via a php script to parse page after login...

Comment: To replicate the login flow in code, you'll have to figure out all the parameters that are sent and how to construct a similar request.  Even then there is no guarantee that you'll be able to convince the destination system that your request is legitimate.  A better approach would be to contact the owner of the destination system and arrange an alternative method of authentication